# Как распарсить html в теле ответа?

Tags: android

Есть ответ от сервера,приходить в формате json, но поле info может быть json 
либо html.Как быть со вторым случаем.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: там не html, а json

Comment: json приходить в виде строки?

Comment: ага, нужно будет вызвать парсер json и передать ему строку и получить заполненный объект

Comment: спасибо, разобрался!